# Mixture of two densities

Tags: statistics, density-function, parameter-estimation

Suppose we have densities $f_1, f_2$ from the random variables $W_1$ and $W_2$ where $W_i$ has known mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i$. Consider the mixture of the two densities $$ f(x;\theta)=\theta f_1(x) + (1-\theta)f_2(x)$$ with $0< \theta < 1$ the unknown mixing proportion. A random sample $X_1, ..., X_n$ from $X \sim f(x;\theta)$ is available.

I calculated the method of moment estimator to be $$\hat{\theta}_n = \frac{\bar{X_n}-\mu_2}{\mu_1-\mu_2}.$$ I was also able to prove that this estimator is unbiased.

I'm now stuck on how to find the variance, MSE and the asymptotic normality result of this estimator.

$\textbf{EDIT : }$

I got the Fisher Information $$I(\theta) = \left(\frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{1}{1 - \theta}\right)^2$$ which I'm not too sure about. But this could easily give me the asymptotic normality result.

I also have a second question: Consider $\sigma=\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ and denote $\Delta = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ and assume $\Delta > 0$ How could one find an approximation for the probability that the method of moment estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ differs more from $\theta$ than a given amount $b > 0$?

$\textbf{EDIT 2: }$ So for the second question I think I have to use the derived asymptotic normality result, but I can't seem to find that first...

Comment: Your unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ for $\theta$ only works if $\mu_1\neq \mu_2$. Is this a valid assumption in the entirety of your problem? Also, from CLT we have $\bar{X}_n\approx\ \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_X,\frac{\sigma_X^2}{n}\right)$ when $n$ is large. This implies $\hat{\theta}_n\approx\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu_X-\mu_2}{\mu_1-\mu_2},\frac{\sigma_X^2}{n(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2}\right)$ when $n$ is large. Do you know how to find $\mu_X$ and $\sigma^2_X$?

Comment: @MatthewH. I'm not sure of the second part of your comment, could you post some clarification?

Comment: A linear combination of normal random variables is normal. For example, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(2,4)$, then $aX+b\sim \mathcal{N}\left(2a+b,4a^2\right)$. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes of course, but I was confused on how to find your $\mu_X$ and $\sigma^2_X$

Comment: $$\mu_X=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x;\theta)\mathrm{d}x=\theta\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_1(x)\mathrm{d}x+(1-\theta)\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_2(x)\mathrm{d}x=\theta\mu_1+(1-\theta)\mu_2$$ Can you use $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)=\sigma_i^2+\mu_i^2$ and $\sigma_X^2=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mu_X^2$ to deduce that $$\mathbb{V}(X)=\theta(\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2)+(1-\theta)(\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2)-\left[\theta\mu_1 + (1-\theta)\mu_2\right]^2$$

Comment: @MatthewH. I appreciate the help! If you could also post an answer so I can accept it as the answer, that would be great! cheers!